# ¿Cómo solucionar error Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined en HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo este error al ejecutar mi pagina html, tengo un html normal

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/utilities.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
        <TITLE>Título de la página</TITLE>
    </HEAD>

    <BODY>
        Aquí iría el contenido de la página
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

pero al ejecutar mi pagina me muestra error en el archivo  "utilerias.js"  contiene lo siguiente:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click','#id_articulo', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('CLICK');
            return false;
        });

});
```

El error me lo marca en la primer linea $(document.....  Ayuda, por favor ya intente varias soluciones y el error sigue.

Comment: la llamada a query va al inicio de tus tres archivos .js

Comment: @alfap muchisimas gracias ya llevaba un rato buscando solución, a que se debe, que tenga que ser el primer archivo de todo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La llamada a tus scripts esta incorrecta, al momento la tienes así

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/utilities.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
```

El problema es que cuando el navegador ejecuta el código de `utilities.js` el llamado a JQUERY todavía no ocurre por eso no reconoce la sintaxis de `$` entonces debe quedar así

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/utilities.js"></script>
```

Dado lo anterior para el momento que se ejecuta el código de `utilities.js` el navegador ya conoce la sintaxis de la librería JQUERY

Answer (score 0):

Deberías poner los scripts al final de tu página justo antes de `</body>` debido a que los scripts en el head bloquearán el renderizado de tu `HTML` hasta que no estén descargados completamente.

El error que tienes es que tus librerías `j3` y `utilities` son dependientes de `JQuery` y cada script al descargarse completamente se ejecuta y continua la descarga de los siguientes scripts, puedes ajustar el orden para que `JQuery` sea el primero en llamarse así cuando las otras dos librerías se ejecuten ya `JQuery` esté disponible.

Si quieres usar los scripts en el `head` puedes usar los atributos `async` o `defer`, según tu caso de uso, para que no se bloquee el renderizado de tu HTML.

```
  <head>

    <!-- descarga el script de forma asíncrona y solo detiene el análisis del HTML en el momento de su ejecución -->
    <script src="mylibraryAsync.js" async></script>

    <!-- descarga el script de forma asíncrona y su ejecución es diferida después que todo el HTML sea analizado -->
    <script src="mylibrary" defer></script>

  </head>
```

Y aunque uses `async` o `defer` siempre debe ser tomado en cuenta el orden de ejecución de cada script.