# Activar Inputs y Boton de enviar al cumplir una condición y agregar/remover clase

Tags: javascript, html5, formularios

Buenas tardes intento desarrollar un login con ciertas funciones en JavaScript que me permita hacer lo siguiente:

Que al llenar el primer Input con un longitud de 7 caracteres se active el segundo Input y se le remueva el Style="background: grey;" y al llenar el segundo Input con una longitud de 7 caracteres se active el boton de Enviar y se le remueva de su clase (class="btn disabled") el atributo (disabled) y el parametro disabled.

Encontre un codigo para guiarme mas o menos, he realizado algunas modificaciones en su función pero no me da resultados.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

    function activarBoton() {
      if (verificar2()) {
        btnEnviar.disabled = false
      } else {
        btnEnviar.disabled = true
      }
    }

    function verificar2() {
      if (caja2.value.length<=7)
        return true;
      return false;
    }

    function activarInput() {
      if (verificar()) {
        caja2.disabled = false
      } else {
        caja2.disabled = true
      }
    }

    function verificar() {
      if (caja1.value.length<=7)
        return false;
      return true;
    }

    var btnEnviar = document.getElementById("btnEnviar");
    btnEnviar.disabled = true;
    var caja1 = document.fr.caja1;
    var caja2 = document.fr.caja2;
        caja2.disabled = true;
    caja1.onkeyup = caja2.onkeyup = activarBoton;
  </script>
```

```html
<form name="fr">
    <input type="text" name="caja1" />
    <input type="text" name="caja2" style="background: grey;"/>
    <button id="btnEnviar" class="btn disabled" type="submit" disabled>enviar</button>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero te recomiendo que tomes tus `inputs`, asignándoles un id, o una clase, como mejor te convenga dependiendo de lo que necesites, una vez tomados estos valores, mandas llamar el `onKeyUp` pero desde el `html`, mandandole como parámetro el valor del `input` que tiene el llamado `onKeyUp(this.value)`, tu función `verificar` y `verificar2` recibirán ese parámetro y en base a eso tomas el tamaño de ese `value` y lo comparas.

Cuando el tamaño del valor de tus `inputs` sea igual a 7, se cumplirán tus condiciones, mientras tanto no.

```js
var btnEnviar = document.getElementById("btnEnviar");
var caja1 = document.getElementById("caja1");
var caja2 = document.getElementById("caja2");

btnEnviar.disabled = true;
caja2.disabled = true;

function verificar2(valor) {
  if (caja2.value.length===7){
    btnEnviar.disabled = false;
    btnEnviar.classList.remove("disabled");
  } else {
      btnEnviar.disabled = true;
  }
}

function verificar(valor) {
  if (valor.length===7){
   caja2.style.background = "#FFFFFF";
    caja2.disabled = false
  } else {
    caja2.style.background = "grey";
    caja2.disabled = true;
    caja2.value = "";
    btnEnviar.disabled = true;
  }
   
}
```

```html
<form name="fr">
    <input id="caja1" type="text" name="caja1" onkeyup="verificar(this.value);" />
    <input id="caja2" type="text" name="caja2" style="background: grey;" onkeyup="verificar2(this.value);"/>
    <button id="btnEnviar" class="btn disabled" type="submit" disabled>enviar</button>
  </form>
```

Espero y sea lo que necesitas.

Comment: Gracias, he intentado compilar el script pero aparentemente hay un problema, el input2 se mantiene activo y el botón al cumplirse la condición no se desactiva

Comment: Edité mi respuesta, espero haber entendido lo que necesitas, ahora las condiciones cambiaron un poco, cuando el input1.length = 7, se activa el input2 y si el input2.length = 7 se activa el botón, pero si el valor del input1 < 7 todo se desactiva.

Comment: btnEnviar.disabled = true; Esta linea en el codigo arroja el siguiente error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'disabled' of null at login.html:7

Comment: Es muy extraño porque ya lo probé y si funciona, en tu codigo tienes creado el boton con el id btnEnviar? Porque el error que te da es que no esta definido el boton.

Answer (score 0):

Deberías agregarle un id a tus inputs para que puedas seleccionarlos con JS o jQuery, después de esto, te recomiendo utilices *listener's* para que no agregues funciones JS en tu HTML de forma lineal, usando la función `keyup` al momento de que el usuario pulse 7 veces o inserte 7 caracteres se hará la validación y pondrá deshabilitado el input, si solo le pones un estilo de `background-color`no le impide al usuario escribir en el otro input así que ponle igualmente `disabled`, cuando reste o agregue otro más se volverá a poner `disabled` y así con el segundo `input` yo le quito el atributo con `removeAttribute()` pero hay otras funciones, utiliza la que más te convenga, cualquier duda hazla saber. :D

```js
var caja1 = document.getElementById('caja1');
var caja2 = document.getElementById('caja2');
var btn = document.getElementById('btnEnviar');

caja1.addEventListener('keyup', function(){
   
    
    if(this.value.length === 7){
      
        console.log('admitido');
        caja2.disabled = false;
        caja2.style.background = 'white';
        
          caja2.addEventListener('keyup',function(){
          
            if(this.value.length === 7){
      
        console.log('admitido');
        btn.disabled = false;
        btn.removeAttribute('class', 'btn disabled');
        
          }else{
           btn.disabled = true;
        btn.setAttribute('class', 'btn disabled');
        
          
          }
          });
        
        
    }else{
    
      console.log('no admitido');
      caja2.disabled = true;
      caja2.value = '';
      caja2.style.background = 'grey';
      
    }


})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="caja1" name="caja1">
<input type="text" id="caja2" name="caja2" disabled style="background: grey;">
<button id="btnEnviar" class="btn disabled" type="submit" disabled>enviar</button>
```

Comment: Gracias Vicky por responder, he probado ell Script pero me pasa lo mismo que al.resto, no compila, es extraño.

Comment: Qué raro que no funcione, aquí si lo hace, te manda algún mensaje de error, puedes verificar en consola oprimiendo **f12**.

Comment: Este es el siguiente error: login.html:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null " caja1.addEventListener('keyup', function(){ "

Answer (score 0):

te propongo esta solución, espero te ayude en algo, en los comentarios del código trato de explicarte lo que hace, buena suerte!

```js
//**Funcionalidad para el input1**
$('input[name=caja1]').on('keyup', () => {

  //Obtenemos el valor
  var input1 = $('.input1').val();

  //Validamos que el valor sea mayor a 7
  if (input1.length > 7) { 
    //Habilitamos el input2 y quitamos el color gris
    $('input[name=caja2]').removeAttr('style').removeAttr('disabled');
  } 
  else {
    //Adicionamos nuevamente el color gris y la propiedad 'disabled' al input2
    $('input[name=caja2]').css('background', 'grey').prop('disabled', true);

    //También bloqueamos el botón
    $('#btnEnviar').addClass('disabled').prop('disabled', true);
  }
});


//**Funcionalidad para el input2**
$('input[name=caja2]').on('keyup', () => {

  //Obtenemos el valor
  var input2 = $('.input2').val();

  //Validamos que el valor sea mayor a 7 caracteres
  if (input2.length > 7) {
    //Habiiltamos el botón quitando la clase 'disabled' y la propiedad 'disabled'
   $('#btnEnviar').removeClass('disabled').removeAttr('disabled');
  } 
  else {
    //Volvemos a deshabilitar el botón, adicionando nuevamente la clase y propiedad 'disabled'
    $('#btnEnviar').addClass('disabled').prop('disabled', true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form name="fr">
  <input type="text" name="caja1" class="input1" />
  <input type="text" name="caja2" class="input2" style="background: grey;" disabled />
  <button id="btnEnviar" class="btn disabled" type="submit" disabled>enviar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte, para ser honesto quería hacerlo sin JQuery y aunque lo compile no responde bien, al cumplir la condición el input 2 no se desactiva, he modificado la variable en la longitud y nada

Comment: Veehh.. Rarísimo, de hecho lo probé de diferentes formas y corre perfectamente, pues el flujo normal como está ahora, es que al escribir 8 caracteres, se activan las funcionalidades, habilitando y deshabiltando elementos(input2-botón), y si no logra los 8 caracteres en ambos inputs, vuelve a deshabilitar elementos.

Comment: El problema es que cuando lo compilo en js.do me dice el siguiente error> "JavaScript error: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined on line 3" y la linea tres es la siguiente> $('input[name=caja1]').on('keyup', () => { / Pero en el compilador del foro me corre perfectamente. Saludos

Comment: Ya corregí el problemas, gracias, solucionado. El problema era el orden el cual puse el script. Saludos https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243536/c%C3%B3mo-solucionar-error-uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined-en-html